# Change Activities' Fragment Inside the Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a Activity, inside that activity I have Fragment.
That Fragment have OnClick method that supposed to
change to another view.
What I want is to change the view inside using the onclick method inside the
Fragment and use the same activity.
[image]

So far this is only what I can do.

```
Fragment mFragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        fragmentClass = LoginSignup.class;
        try {
            mFragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception mE) {
            Log.e(TAG, mE.toString());
        }

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragment).commit();
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: I need to change the activities fragment inside the first fragment.

Comment: You can't change activity from fragment in same view. Instead of you can call child fragment !

Comment: Have you read [Communicating With Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) in the official docs? Also, you use a very unorthodox method for creating a new Fragment.

Comment: Unorthodox? what do you mean?

Comment: Using a `Class` object and casting it to `Fragment`. Typically there's a static `newInstance()` method inside the `Fragment` class which returns a new Fragment and assigns any arguments to it in the process. It's called with `Fragment.newInstance()` (example shown in the [dcoumentation here a couple of paragraphs down](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) )

Comment: simply open new fragment on button click. can't it solve your problem?

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks.

Comment: @RahulSharma I Want to replace the Current fragment into another fragment using the same activity. Sorry. Im new using fragments.

Comment: @CharlesGalvez added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method

```
public static void openFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment targetFragment) {

    try {

        String fragmentName = targetFragment.getClass().getName();
        manager.popBackStack();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout, targetFragment, fragmentName)
                .addToBackStack(fragmentName)
                .commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

call this method each time when you are opening your fragment. You have to pass two params to this method. **targetFragment** is the fragment you want to open.

Comment: This is greate. Thanks sir. This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) notify activity or implement interface to change fragment in fragment.

**Interface：**

```
public interface LoginViewInterface {

     void moveToLoginView();

     void moveToInsertView();   
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class LoginActivity implements LoginViewInterface {

    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    private List<BaseFragment> fragmentList;
    private LoginFragment loginFragment;
    private InsertFragment insertFragment;

    private void InitFragment(){
        manager = getFragmentManager();
        insertFragment = (LogModeFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.login_insert);
        loginFragment = (LoginFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.login_login);
        insertFragment.InitInterface(this);
        loginFragment.InitInterface(this);
        fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        fragmentList.add(loginFragment);
        fragmentList.add(insertFragment);
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentList.get(0))
                .hide(fragmentList.get(1));
        transaction.show(fragmentList.get(0)). commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }


    @Override
    public void moveToLoginView() {
         transaction.hide(fragmentList.get(0));
         transaction.show(fragmentList.get(1));
         transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();       
    }

    @Override
    public void moveToInsertView() {
        transaction.hide(fragmentList.get(1));
        transaction.show(fragmentList.get(0));
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
class InsertFragment extends BaseFragment{
    LoginViewInterface dataInterface;
    public void InitInterface(LoginViewInterface dataInterface) {
        this.dataInterface = dataInterface;
    }

    private doChange(){
        dataInterface.moveToInsertView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I already got the answer. But Ill take a look at this too. It might help me in the future. thanks :)